# my box has been upgraded to AFCI breakers Tennessee?

Tags: wiring, gfci, afci

I have an old house, my box has been upgraded to AFCI breakers. Can I replace the 2 prong plugs with GFCI plugs & the "GFCI PROTECTED / NO EQUIPT GROUND" labels & meet code requirements for Tennessee?

Comment: What wiring type was your house wired with?  Also, do you have any shared neutrals anywhere in the house, and what make/series are your breakers?

Comment: Are the breakers combined GFCI/AFCI? If so, you don't need separate GFCI sockets.